# Application to handle registration to Intercom on subsequent login after registration on my app in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, api, registration, intercom

If a user is registered and tries to login and the intercom registration is not done, App will register the user to intercom on successful OTP verification. and If Intercom registration succeeds, then user will move normally in the app. if not, then user will see a message that Support function will not work, as user could not be registered with support.
and Next time on login, again App will try to register the user.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do intercom or mixpanel registration then do:-

```
onTap: () 
{
    MixPanelHelper.trackEvent(MixpanelEvents.______);
},
```

in "______", You have to input that on which ontap feature or on click of which button or text, mixpanel will track your events.

This helped me to resolve the issue.